# Update of table1 with table2 values using SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to update table1 with table2 mobile number, the common column in table1 and table2 is name, but table1 name is mixed with initial, table2 only has the name.

Can anyone tell how to update table1?

I've tried this:

```
update table1 
set table1.mobile = table2.mobile 
from table1 
join table2 on table1.name = table2.name
```

Table1

```
Name    Mobile
abc 123
def 456
```

Table2

```
Name    Mobile
abc  x  null
def  Y  Null
```

I want to update table1 mobile in table2  mobile

I tried 
update table1 set table1.mobile=table2.mobile from table1 
       join table2 on table1.name=table2.name

Comment: Show us your data.

Comment: table1 columns (name : anil, mobile: 123);  table2 columns(name: anil y, mobile: null)

Comment: Edit your question and include all relevant data/information there

Comment: Whats the actual problem? Do you get an error? post it. Do you get an unexepcted outcome? explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using sub-query.

```
update table1 set table1.mobile = (select TOP 1 table2.mobile from table2 where table2.name = substring(table1.name, 0, charindex(' ', table1.name)))
```

Edit:

I did a substring on the first word of the column value. The "anil y" will now be "anil".

Comment: Hope that you missed this point in the question `table1 name is mixed with inital , table2 having only name`

Comment: thanks for your quick response but  it is updating all rows in table but i want to update single row in table matching with name in both tables

Comment: @un-lucky my bad i missed it,

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
Create table #table1
(
name varchar(10),
mobile int
)
insert into #table1 values ('Anil', 123)
insert into #table1 values ('abc', 888)
insert into #table1 values (NULL, 321)

Create table #table2
(
name varchar(10),
mobile int
)
insert into #table2 values ('Anil y', NULL)
insert into #table2 values ('z abc', NULL)
insert into #table2 values (NULL, NULL)

Update #table2
Set #table2.mobile = #table1.mobile
from #table2, #table1
Where charindex(#table1.name, #table2.name) > 0

Select * from #table2
```

**Output:**

```
Anil y  123
z abc   888
NULL    NULL
```

Comment: same number displaying for all rows